# remove or hide header navigationView in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

i am using design 23.1.1 in my project. i want drawer without header. just menu items are enough. i dont add any header view(programmatically or in XML). but in drawer i have empty header. please help me how to remove this empty header.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
      />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  View headerView= LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, null);
        navigationView.addHeaderView(headerView);
navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

i use dummy layout. and solved my problem but i think it is ridiculous.

Comment: What is the import you are using for NavigationView? I am using navigationView from design support library and is unable to find the method "navigationView.getHeaderView()".

Answer (score 2):

If You want to remove header:

```
navigationView.removeHeaderView(navigationView.getHeaderView(0));
```

Of cource if You have more haeders You have to do this in some loop to remove them all. 0 is index of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your style file `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>`

and remove `app:headerLayout` from navigationView xml.

and add this to your navigationView xml :

```
android:layout_marginTop ="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
```

it worked perfect for me.

Answer (score -3):

To remove it permanently:

The Layout that contains the NavigationView widget is like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

Just remove the app:headerLayout line from it:

```
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
```

Comment: Headers comes again after removing headerLayout from navigationView..How to fix it?