# how to replace the Android NavigationView HeaderView

Tags: android, replace, android-navigationview

I have two different header xml layouts and want to switch between them programmatically. My problem is that the old layout is not replaced by the new but instead I end up with two header layouts. I read many [Answers1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621047/customising-navigationview-adding-dynamic-headerview-android-support-design-l) , [Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970781/remove-or-hide-header-navigationview-in-android) but it does not work.

Here´s what i try: and if i run this code 3 times I have 3 headers instead of replacing the header layout. I think I must delete the `navigate.getHeaderView(0)` first but how?

```
NavigationView navigate = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigate.getMenu().clear();
    navigate.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_navigation_exit);
    navigate.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_view_header_exit);
    View header = navigate.getHeaderView(0);
    streetViewImage = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.street_view_image);
    streetViewImage.set....
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the reference of the header view and then remove it when you want to replace it with something else.

`navigate.removeHeaderView(previousHeaderView)`

Comment: That is working but wanted to ask Is this a recommended  way to do what I want or is there a better way?